sqlalchemy raw query timestamp
I'm trying to execute a raw SQL query in SQLAlchemy, but I'm encountering syntax errors. Here's the SQL query I'm trying to run:
WITH RECURSIVE dates AS (
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2024-04-01 00:00:00' AS date
  UNION ALL
  SELECT date + INTERVAL '1 DAY'
  FROM dates
  WHERE date < TIMESTAMP '2024-04-30 23:59:59'
)
SELECT dates.date::date,
       COALESCE(json_agg(json_build_object(
           'time_start', ds.time_start,
           'schedule_id', ds.id,
           'doctor_id', ds.doctor_id,
           'doctor_name', d.name,
           'time_end', ds.time_end,
           'quota', ds.quota,
           'day', ds.day
       )), '[]') AS schedules
FROM dates
LEFT JOIN doctors_schedules ds ON EXTRACT(DOW FROM dates.date) = ds.day_number
LEFT JOIN doctors d on ds.doctor_id = d.id
GROUP BY dates.date
ORDER BY dates.date;

i did tried with
query = text("""
    WITH RECURSIVE dates AS (
      SELECT TIMESTAMP '':start_date'' AS DATE
      UNION ALL
      SELECT date + INTERVAL ''1 DAY''
      FROM dates
      WHERE date < TIMESTAMP '':end_date'' AS DATE
    )
    SELECT dates.date::date,
          COALESCE(json_agg(json_build_object(
              ''time_start'', ds.time_start,
              ''schedule_id'', ds.id,
              ''doctor_id'', ds.doctor_id,
              ''doctor_name'', d.name,
              ''time_end'', ds.time_end,
              ''quota'', ds.quota,
              ''day'', ds.day
          )), ''[]'') AS schedules
    FROM dates
    LEFT JOIN doctors_schedules ds ON EXTRACT(DOW FROM dates.date) = ds.day_number
    LEFT JOIN doctors d on ds.doctor_id = d.id
    WHERE ds.clinic_id = :clinic_id
    GROUP BY dates.date
    ORDER BY dates.date;
    """)

start_date = '2024-01-01 00:00:00'
end_date = '2024-01-31 23:59:59'

params = {"start_date": start_date, "end_date": end_date, "clinic_id": clinic_id}

result = await session.execute(query, params)

However, I keep getting a syntax error near $1. Can someone please help me understand what's causing this error and how to fix it? Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

You don't need the (doubled) single quotes around the parameters - SQLAlchemy will handle the quoting.
